# MVC Authorize attribute deny

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, authorization

I'm using the `Authorize()` attribute to secure my controllers/actions and want to only display the Login action to unauthenticated users - or to put it another way, deny access to authenticated users.

I haven't been able to find anything on the web dealing with either denying permission or allowing negative permissions (ie !LoggedIn)

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

MVC2, .Net 4

**EDIT:** To clairfy, I want something like this:

```
Public Class PublicController
    Inherits ControllerBase

    <Authorize()> 'Only logged-in users can logout
    Public Function Logout() as ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    'Something here to indicate that only NON-authorized users should see this action
    Public Function Login() as ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: it's not clear what your issue is. Any controller/action method you decorate with `[Authorize]` will by default be restricted to authenticated users. In other words, if you're not logged in, you won't be able to execute those controllers/actions. What else do you want to restrict/allow?

Comment: Just guessing here, Basiclife; Do you mean that if someone is already logged in, but just not in an appropriate Role for the version of Authorize() that takes roles/user names, you want something other than them being directed to the login page?

Comment: If Andrew's correct, a quick search in google with "mvc authorize" yield something like: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clear - I'll edit the question

Comment: I suggest you look at creating a custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute. As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2383094/148403

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this:

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea - The only problem is that I'm using the atributes to allow Telerik menu to securty trim my sitemap - I'm not sure if it will detect custom attributes (although I would hope so!). I'll give it a shot and get back to you in a day or so

Comment: @Basiclife - It will, I'm familiar with some of their stuff, should pick up custom attributes fine.  - Also this is the sort of thing you should include in your question.  What kind of components your hoping to integrate this with would change the answer.

Comment: There are two serious security bugs with this code. First, for AuthorizeCore isn't called AllowAnonymousAttribute is applied  - the deny rules would fail to execute in that case. Second, simply negating the base result (!base.AuthorizeCore) does not correctly apply the rules. If both  "Users" and "Roles" are specified, the role rules will fail to be evaluated.