# Asp.net MVC Role manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, roleprovider

I am using role manager and windows authentication for my asp.net mvc project
we have 2 Roles which are viewers and Editors .

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
        <providers>
          <clear />
          <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Editor can access the whole application but Viewer can only access two actions

I first tried to put Authorize attribute for base controller which just allow editor to access everything :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Editors")]
public class BaseController : Controller
```

and then add Authorize attribute to those two action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Viewers,Editors")]
public ActionResult Report(PaymentsUnallocatedAndQueriedModel model)
```

it does not work ,it does not allow viewer to access any action which make sense now.

I believe it is not a good idea to repeat Authorize attribute on the top of each action.

Could you please tell me if there is a better solution to that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look at this from a tree perspective. In order to get to an action, you must first be able to get to a controller. In this case, you've restricted the controller to the Editors group, so Viewers can't even get that far. What would most likely be more helpful would be to restrict the controller to `Viewers, Editors` and then in the actions that require Editor only permission, specify those. This will generate redundant attributes, but consider the code cost if you had to manually restrict each action based on role membership.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Viewers, Editors")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    [Authorize(Roles = "Editors")]
    public ActionResult EditReport(PaymentsUnallocatedAndQueriedModel model)
    {
        // Some editor only functionality
    }

    public ActionResult Report(PaymentsUnallocatedAndQueriedModel model)
    {
        // Some functionality for both. No attribute needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer, I was hoping not to repeat authorize on the top of each action, because editors can access every actions but it seems there are no other way

Comment: @Elham: You could always look at this SO question and implement a deny attribute. This seems like a lot of work simply because you don't want to type out an attribute for a method though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011458/mvc-authorize-attribute-deny