# Distinguishing controller actions using authorization filters for caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm trying to come up with a way to cache the actions in a controller only for anonymous users using the `[OutputCache(Duration = 3600]` annotation. E.g.:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
[ActionName("Test")]
public async Task<ViewResult> Test() {...}
```

In my research I came across a very clever way to use [ActionMethodSelectionAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383094/distinguishing-controller-actions-using-authorization-filters) for exactly this, but as soon as the anonymous action is cached it applies for both the anonymous and authorized version.

I need this caching for the front page and for information pages. In all cases the top menu will be different for authorized users. The problem is that the menu is a partial added in the _Layout and so cached together with the rest of the action. E.g:

```
<body>
    <div class="contain-to-grid oversizedContainer">
        @Html.Action("Menu", "Framework")
    </div>

    @RenderBody()
```

The second problem is that on the information pages some of what is displayed will depend on if the user is autherized (checked using razor @if !Request.IsAuthenticated) and data in the view model (@Model).

I'd prefer something that would not require me to rewrite all my views.

PS! I'm aware of `VaryByParam`, but the actions do not take any parameters and are linked to directly.

Comment: I suppose [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2109928/1849444) is what you're lookint for.

Comment: The solution in the link looks like what I want, although it looks like the accepted answer may not be the best one, but rather the one below. I haven't tested it as in the end I decided to separate everything into partials so I could use annotation (as shown above) to cache only content that is not specific to authorized users. This does not work if content cannot be so separated. Also, note that partials cannot have a different cache setting from the cached action that invokes the partials (this would have been nice to set only specific partials to not be cached).